# Amazon redshift spectrum under the hood?

Tags: amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am just curious to know when you run a query in Redshift spectrum what's happening under the hood?
Is it running a `spark` job? or `map-reduce` job or `presto` or something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive but I believe Spectrum was based off Apache Impala.  At this point I'd imagine the code is hardly recognizable as Impala though -- Spectrum has been under active development for quite a while now.

I'm guessing Impala based off Spectrum's capabilities/behavior as relates to timestamps in Parquet files.